# Why are all the gems with native extensions failing to install when I run bundle install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby 2.2.5 and `bundle install` fails to install gems with native extension. 
Here is the error I get for json gem.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/Mr_AdeyBee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160724-3304-1j34bow.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
compiling crypt.c
compiling crypt_blowfish.c
compiling crypt_gensalt.c
compiling wrapper.c
linking shared-object bcrypt_ext.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/travis/.sm/pkg/active/lib'

make "DESTDIR=" install
make: /usr/local/bin/gmkdir: No such file or directory
make: *** [.RUBYARCHDIR.time] Error 1

make install failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Mr_AdeyBee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Mr_AdeyBee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.2.0-static/bcrypt-3.1.11/gem_make.out
```

Also here is the error for byebug.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/Mr_AdeyBee/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160724-3304-1vjgvan.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling breakpoint.c
compiling byebug.c
compiling context.c
compiling locker.c
compiling threads.c
linking shared-object byebug/byebug.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/travis/.sm/pkg/active/lib'

make "DESTDIR=" install
make: /usr/local/bin/gmkdir: No such file or directory
make: *** [.RUBYARCHDIR.-.byebug.time] Error 1

make install failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/Mr_AdeyBee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/gems/byebug-9.0.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/Mr_AdeyBee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.5/extensions/x86_64-darwin-15/2.2.0-static/byebug-9.0.5/gem_make.out
```

I have tried installing with `sudo` and I get the same result. I have also tried a couple of results from google suggestions and I seem not to find a suitable solution.

Ruby Version -> 2.2.5
Rails Version -> 4.2.5

How can I get over this?

Comment: Who is Travis? Where is that coming from. And do you have Xcode and all the command line tools installed?(looks like OS X based on /Users)

Comment: I don't have any user named Travis and I really don't know why it is looking for that directory.

Comment: maybe reinstalling bundle gem might help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
    > brew install coreutils
    > gem install json
```